# How can I use a database schema in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, global-variables, database-schema

I am writing a small PHP/MySQL application for personal use. This is my first time using PHP, so bear with me.

I wanted to be able to change the DB schema afterwards, if needed, so everything went into variables (stuff like table and column names). I used two approaches during development:

- Global variables

db_schema.php:

```
$table = "table_name";
$column = "column_name";
```

main.php:

```
function do_db_stuff()
{
    global $table;
    global $column;
    global $db;
    $db->query("SELECT `$column_name` FROM `$table_name`;");
}
```

- Defines

db_schema.php:

```
define (TABLE, "table_name");
define (COLUMN, "column_name");
```

main.php:

```
function do_db_stuff()
{
    global $db;
    $db->query("SELECT `" . COLUMN . "` FROM `" . TABLE . "`;");
}
```

Now, I like the nice syntax of the query string when I use variables - I do not need to use `.` concatentation, however this approach requires an unwieldy number of `global` statements at the beginning of each function. This was a dealbreaker. Approach number two does away with the `global`s, but the syntax is not so nice.

Is there a time-tried PHP-style solution to this problem?

Comment: [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Component_interactions), for example ?

Comment: How does one make the leap from switching schemas to the MVC pattern? @HAL9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on the following solution which seems the most clean to me:

- db_schema.php

  ```
  $TABLE = "table";
  $COL = "column";
  ```
- main.php

  ```
  function do_stuff
  {
      require 'db_schema.php';
      $db->query("SELECT `$COL` FROM `$TABLE`;);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$schema = array(
    'table' => 'spam',
    'column' => 'eggs',
);

function do_db_stuff() {
    global $db;
    global $schema;
    $sql = sprintf(
        'SELECT `%s` FROM `%s`',
        $schema['table'],
        $schema['column']
    );
    $db->query( $sql );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution which is pretty clean-looking:

- db_schema.php

  ```
  $table = "table";
  $column = "column";
  ```
- main.php

  ```
  function do_stuff() 
  {
      require "db_schema.php";
      $db->query("SELECT `$column` FROM `$table`;");
  }
  ```